# Haml syntax highlight in Sublime Text 2 for .hamlc templates

Tags: coffeescript, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, hamlc, jst

I installed the HAML textmate bundle, that display syntax highlight for .haml templates, but I also have Coffee HAML templates that are named like

```
layout.jst.hamlc
```

and I would like to add syntax highlight as well.

The Ruby Haml syntax is good enough, so I usually just change the language to Ruby Haml,
but then when I close and open the file again, Sublime Text 2 forgets it and I have to assign it again and again.

Is there a way to automatically assign the ruby Haml syntax highlight for .hamlc files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the language selection menu (click on "Plain Text" in the bottom right), at the very top is "Open all with current extension as", which expands to another list of languages. Pick `User` > `Rails` > `Ruby Haml` from there and it will remember that for hamlc files.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Awesome. So this is a more generic answer that will work for other formats I may use in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I just added a [**hamlc** syntax definition](https://github.com/jisaacks/CoffeeScriptHaml) to [package control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) for Sublime.

Comment: Sadly, this no longer highlights the Coffee portions of the file.